# React app doesn't load in Ingress if I specify the path

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

This is my third post on this issue, and hopefully - the last one. The thing is - I am making a project for my university, and I have 3 kubernetes pods - one with a react app, which is supposed to connect to a second pod with an express app, which connects to a mongo database. I configure the links for connecting those using enviromental variables. So, those pods work by themselves, but now when I set up an ingress for them, there is a problem:

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: frontend-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /frontend
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: frontend-service
            port:
              number: 3001
      - path: /backend
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: backend-service
            port:
              number: 5001
```

Here, as you can see, I specify the path for the frontend service as `/frontend` and the backend service as `/backend`. The weird thing is that if I try to open `http://localhost/frontend`, it will seemingly find the link, but the page just appears to be empty, even though the browser tab title seems to change properly, and the dev mode in the browser seems to show some default template react code. **BUT, if I just put `path: /` for `path: /frontend` for frontend, the page loads properly.** The backend also works fine if I put the empty path for it instead, but I can't set the same path for both services. How do I solve this issue so I can properly access both?

I am using minikube. If you need it, here is the configuration for my backend and frontend deployments and services:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: frontend
          image: cloud-frontend
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3001
          env:
            - name: REACT_APP_API_URL
              value: "http://localhost"
            - name: PORT
              value: "3001"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: frontend-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: frontend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 3001
      targetPort: 3001
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: backend-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: backend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: backend
          image: cloud-backend
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5001
          env:
            - name: PORT
              value: "5001"
            - name: DBLINK
              value: "mongodb://database-service:27017/TODO"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: backend-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: backend
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5001
      targetPort: 5001
  type: ClusterIP
```